# Gulp extract text from a file

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to build up a table of contents file based on the comments from the first line of each file.

I can get to the files no problem and read the contents, but that only returns a buffer of the file.

I want the check if the first line is comments.  if it is then extract that line and add it to a new file.

```
var bufferContents = through.obj(function(file,enc,cb){ 
    console.log(file.contents);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is pretty large, I would recommend use lazy module.
https://github.com/jpommerening/node-lazystream

Or if line length is specified, you can set chunk size.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426486/1502019

Comment: The answer was much simpler than these answers, but they pointed me in the right direction, and I can use the chunk size as I only need to read the first line of the file which will be relatively small.

The answer in my case was to use 
    file.contents.toString('utf8')